# ERROR - Get temperature failed for Adapter=1

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg

Have combed all the forums and tried a dozen different approaches to diagnosing & resolving this, to no avail. `amdconfig --odgt --adapter=all` only retrieves temp for `adapter=0`, but gives the above error for any and all other GPUs.

`lspci | grep VGA` correctly identifies all cards. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, on fresh install of latest AMD crimson drivers (stable) with no other apparent issues. I did do `amdconfig --initial -f --adapter=all` upon installation of drivers (Newly installed catalyst (15.30.1025-x86.x86_64), on Ubuntu 14.04.3. I have encountered the same problem on three different machines/installations, and in fact various other --od commands encounter the same problem. All GPU's are working, `aticonfig --list-adapters` shows them as expected. But `--odgt commands` only work for default `adapter=0`. When I run `AMDOverdriveCtrl`, it shows only `adapter=0` as active, all others inactive. However, I can confirm that all GPU's are in fact running fine. It's just that I can only get temps on `adapter=0`, be it through `--odgt` or using additional tools/interfaces.

I did try manually adding devices to `xorg.conf` - but after save/reboot, when I check `xorg.conf` it has been reverted to the previous config and my changes have been overwritten. Not sure modifying xorg would have solved my problem, but I do notice only adapter=0 is listed under "devices" in the `.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which solved by editing xorg.conf file.

1. Make backup of current xorg.conf by:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
   ```
2. Make new xorg.conf by:

   ```
   sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
   ```
3. Edit /etc/init/gpu-manager.conf by commenting first four rows:

   ```
   #start on (starting lightdm
   #          or starting kdm
   #          or starting xdm
   #          or starting lxdm)
   task
   exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
   ```
4. Reboot
5. Try to get temps by:

   ```
   aticonfig --adapter=ALL --od-gettemperature
   ```